# Puppet file_line doesn't work with agent rather with apply

Tags: regex, puppet

I am trying to add a line and replace others with puppet `file_line` resource. I have a very strange behavior. Here is the code:

```
file_line { 'bashrc':
  ensure => present,
  path   => '/user/.bashrc',
  line   => 'HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace:erasedups',
  match  => '^HISTCONTROL\=',
}

file_line { 'sysctl_conf':
  ensure => present,
  path   => '/etc/sysctl.conf',
  line   => 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1',
  notify => Exec['/sbin/sysctl -p'],
}
```

I have this line: `HISTCONTROL=ignoredups` in the `.bashrc` file. When I run `puppet agent -t` it just appends this line `HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace:erasedups` to the file and the original line `HISTCONTROL=ignoredups` is still there. More interesting is that the second `file_line` resource istn't executed at all.
But when I run `puppet apply -e "include module"`, the line in `.bashrc` is replaced and the `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` is appended to `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

System information:

```
root@puppet [Home]:~# puppet agent --version
5.5.8
root@puppet [Home]:~# puppet --version
5.5.8
root@puppet [Home]:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
root@puppet [Home]:~# puppet module list | grep stdlib
├── puppetlabs-stdlib (v5.1.0)
```

Can someone explain this please, or how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: The problem with the first resource is that you are escaping the `=` and it is not a special character. The rest of the behavior indicates something else is going on here beyond the information provided.

Comment: Thanks Matt, that resolved the problem with first resource. I am still looking into the second one.

Comment: I could fix the problem by restarting puppetserver. It seems like after changing a catalog the server must be restarted. I didn't know that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: On older versions of puppet, you would need to restart the puppet server if you changed the code for a custom function. Does that apply here?

Comment: I have the recent version provided by Ubuntu Xenial `5.5.8`, I thought it is not needed to restart the server, but obviously it is, so I added the service restart line to my r10k script. And the only changes I made were in my own modules

Comment: Just to clarify, the first `file_line` resource was already in the manifests with the escaped `\=`. After removing it the resource runs correctly, I added the second `file_line`resource today and it appended the line only after restarting puppetserver. So it seams the cache wasn't updated after running `r10k`, although the changes were present on the server. I didn't make any further changes except adding the second `file_line` resource to the manifest.

Comment: Oh yeah it was using a cached catalog and not refreshing; that does happen sometimes. Note sometimes you do have to blow away the r10k/code manager cache too on failed deploys.

Comment: Maybe that is the better way, just to purge `/var/cache/r10k/*`. Thank you Matt

Comment: Note that there are configuration options controlling [whether and how frequently the server times out its cache](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/configuration.html#environmenttimeout).  I would recommend turning off that caching In a development environment or if your master is only lightly loaded.

Comment: Thanks John, indeed. I had the `unlimited` option in my `puppet.conf`. Great